# Unable to install googlefinance with conda

Tags: conda, google-finance

I just discovered the Anaconda project and think it's AMAZING!  I just ran into an issue installing `googlefinance`, however:

Unable to find with a search:

```
(env)me@vm$ conda search googlefinance
Fetching package metadata: ....
```

Found with pip:

```
pip install googlefinance
```

Can I get it from this `hargup` user?
https://anaconda.org/hargup/googlefinance/files

I'm just really trying to not mix pip and conda in this environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide the channel to `conda` and it should work:

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/hargup/channel/pypi googlefinance
```

Even if there would be be no `conda` package, mixing `conda` and `pip` installations is fine. `conda` "knows" about the pip-installed packages.

Comment: ahhh, i was not passing a uri, just the username.  thank you!

Comment: that seems to install successfully but fails on usage with error: `ImportError: No module named 'googlefinance'`.  other people online seem to suggest needs to be run as an administrator/elevated permission? `sudo`?

Comment: Do you  you have multiple Python installations?

Comment: i moved my shebang line in the top-level python file from using `#!/usr/bin/python3` to `#!/usr/bin/env python3` and things are working now...